# Выделение памяти с помощью операции new

Tags: указатели, c++

Немогу понять в чем разница между следующими двумя операторами

```
int *pt = new int;
*pt = 1001;

cout << "location = " << pt << " location of pointer pt: " << &pt << endl;

Вывод:
--------------------------------------
location = 0x1001000e0 
location of pointer pt: 0x7fff5fbff840
```

Почему pt и &pt указывают на два разных адреса. Разве это не одно и тоже?

Comment: сколько людей поломало голову об указатели))

Comment: @skyboy: если бы `pt` и `&pt` означали одно и то же, зачем нужен был бы в языке `&`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pt - это указатель, а &pt - это адрес памяти, где хранится указатель. Они не могут быть равными.

Comment: Ну, случайно могут:

    void* p;
    p = (void*)&p;

Comment: Т.е. в примере, приведенном мною выше pt - это адрес значения 1001, а &pt - это адрес самой переменной. Правильно ли я вас понял?

Comment: в pt будет храниться адрес, по которому сохранено 1001. Но этому адресу где то нужно храниться. и `&pt` как раз показывает его.

Comment: Почему не могут? Если int в этой ОС подходящего размера, то вполне.
*pt = &pt;

int* pt; // указатель на целое. Переменная содержит адрес, по которому лежит целое (int равное 1001)

&pt; // это уже адрес самой переменной pt, которая содержит адрес, по которому лежит целое (int равное 1001)

В доме, который построил Джек.

Comment: в том примере, который привел пользователь они навряд ли будут равными. адреса с первого килобайта редко так просто выделяются (в большинстве случаев система в этих адресах хранит таблицу прерываний).

Answer (score 3):

Указатель, это **переменная**, которая **содержит адрес другой переменной**.

`cout<<p` делает вывод содержимого указателя, которое, как сказано выше, является адресом.

`cout<<&p` делает вывод адреса самой переменной-указателя, а не его содержимого.

Comment: Остается добавить, что

    cout << *p

выведет `1001`, т.е. число, на которое указывает `p`.